# Python Pandas replace substring if string starts with

Tags: python, string, pandas, function, replace

I am trying to write the following function:

```
def d (row):
    if df['name'].str.startswith('"'):
        return df['name'].str.replace("'","''")
    else:
        return df['name']
df['name2'] = df.apply(lambda row: d(row), axis=1)
```

I am trying to add a second apostrophe whenever a string has a single apostrophe within a contraction.  this only appears when i have double quoted strings.

I continue to get a ' KeyError: ('name', occurred at index 0')

this only happens a few times in my dataset, but i need to replace "jack's place" with "jack''s place" so that i can inject this into a sql query.

Comment: Looks like you might be missing a ] in your first return line

Comment: Thanks Chris, yes, I missed it in my question, but the issue still persists as i did not miss it in my script

Comment: can you post a few rows of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you do a full replace:

```
df['name2'] = df['name'].str.replace('\'', '"')
print(df)

           name         name2
0           ABC           ABC
1           SDF           SDF
2  jack's place  jack"s place
3  jack's place  jack"s place
4  jack's place  jack"s place
```

Comment: Thank you!  the dataset i am currently pulling has 100+ names, most of them are normally formatted strings without contractions.  I am pulling the output from one SQL server and then injecting into another sql server via python, most instances the output is 'name 1', 'name 2', but there are a few that look like "jack's place" - so my intention was to step 1: add additional apostrophe for strings with contractions, and then step 2, replace all instances of double quotes with single quotes- if i remove all instances of single quotes that will hurt the injection of strings back into sql query

Comment: @John if you're moving this data between DBs, the DB connectors, if used correctly, should take care of this automatically! I strongly suggest you try to use the connectors correctly instead of hacking the string values of the columns.

Comment: Thanks Dave!  I will continue to try, doing this between SQL Server and SQL Server (2 diff servers) has been fine, but i am going to try between SQL Server and Teradata which the latter seems significantly less flexible, so i wanted to see if i could do this manually before working with Teradata- I appreciate your insight, but any help anyone can provide with how to do this, would be great!  I know that within SQL server if i set quoted_identifier to off, i have no issues, but without this line of code, i am running into problems in SQL Server